# How to add select html to my own contact form "In Wordpress"

Tags: wordpress, forms, select, contacts

I created my own contact form wordpress. I can send "name" "e-mail" .. But i can't send html select info and checkbox value. Can you help me please?

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
```

And using this php:

```
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];

$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your select input a name.

for example:

```
<label for='vehicle-brand'>Select a vehicle brand:</label><br>
<select name="vehicle-brand">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

the code for your checkbox looks good. To learn more about using checkboxes in PHP forms try this link: http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
```

Then to post this info.

```
$vehiclebrand = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["vehicle-brand"] );

$vehicle = ( isset( $_POST["vehicle"] ) && $_POST['vehicle'] == 'Car' ? esc_attr( $_POST["vehicle"] ) : '' );
```

Then you need to add these variables in your message to receive them.

It is a good idea to sanitize your variables for security of your WordPress website. The sanitize_text_field() function is a WordPess function, you can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

I hope that helps.